# How do I implement Any Origin to circumvent the same origin policy using dashcode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, same-origin-policy, dashcode

I'm trying to use the JQuery code in dashcode, but I have no idea what to put as the datasource, or if I can even use datasource with JQuery.  Can anyone help or point to helpful documentation? Thanks for your help, I'm completely new to dashcode and JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to jQuery or dashcode, but it may help you:

Create a js file `data.js` with a content like:
`processData({"who":"Davis"});`

Add both SCRIPT tags below to your HTML page:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <script>
    function processData(data){
      alert(data.who);
    }
  </script>
  <script src="data.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

data.js is JSON data wrapped into a function that is available in your page.

This technique to load data from any origin is called [JSONP](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/)